# How to move the caret to the beginning of a multiline textbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a text box in windows forms which is set to Multiline. I have a `KeyDown` event handler which recognizes the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the textbox and does something and then clears the text from the textbox. How can I move the caret to the beginning of textbox programmatically? I can see it when I press Ctrl + Home in the textbox.
I tried the below using `SelectionStart` property but it leaves the cursor at the beginning of second line.

```
Private Sub txtComments_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtComments.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If txtComments.TextLength > 0 Then
            AddSelection(txtComments.Text)
            txtComments.Clear()
        End If

        If txtComments.TextLength = 0 Then
            txtComments.Focus()
            txtComments.SelectionStart = 0
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're clearing the control and focussing at the start of the control *before* the actual `KeyPress` event is handled by the underlying control, so pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> still adds a new line to the control *after* all your code has run, which is why you end up on the second line.

You can prevent this behaviour by using the [`SuppressKeyPress` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `KeyEventArgs` passed in to your event handler:

```
Private Sub txtComments_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtComments.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If txtComments.TextLength > 0 Then
            AddSelection(txtComments.Text)
            txtComments.Clear()
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The documentation for this property says:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the key event should be passed on to the underlying control.

and:

> You can assign **true** to this property in an event handler such as KeyDown in order to prevent user input.

Comment: @Jyina No problems.  I just edited the answer - the code in the event handler can be a lot shorter - there's no need to check the length = 0 or refocus back in the control.